# Magento use categories path for product URLs on search result page for SEO

Tags: product, catalog, search, seo

We currently have Magento setup to "use categories path for product URLs", this ensures the category url key is applied in-between the domain and product key.

**Working correct URL**

```
http://domain.com/category/product.html
```

It works perfectly however when you search for products using the "quick search" the product links on the resulting page do not have the category key in them and hence the product links do not work?

**Not working incorrect URL search page**

```
http://domain.com/product.html
```

How can I change the quick search result page to use the categories path in the product URLs?

Comment: Given that a product can be placed in multiple categories, how would search determine which category to use in the link?

Comment: Well in this example they'd only be in 1 category.

Comment: Like Cags told you the category is not selected so the normal url came as output. But if you enable "Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products" at the backend you hopefully get teh crawler to the correct site

Answer (score 2):

The category path is added based on the registry value for `current_category`. Since there is none on search it doesn't add a category.

In order to get this to work you wold need to overwrite the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url` method `getCategoryId` to fall back on the products assigned categories when no category is registered.

It would look something like this

```
   public function getCategoryId()
   {
      if ($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
         return $category->getId();
      } else {
         $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
         return count(categories) ? reset(categories) : false ;
      }
   }
```