# Magento 2: Get product URL with category key on Search page

Tags: magento2

I just apply Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to "Yes"

this settings  working fine if we access product from **category page** but if we **search product by name and in search in show direct product URL without category key** so how can I fixed this issue anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/55906/59677

Comment: For magento 2 no such function found on Url.php file..... <vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Url.php